# Can't use a method from an object in a ArrayList in a HashMap

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I'm trying to write a stock market simulation.
Sorry that I wrote the code in german, but that was easier for me...
So for understanding: Aktie==stock, Boerse== stock market

In the class "Boerse" I have a HashMap with ArrayLists inside, in these ArrayLists are objects of the class "Aktie".

Now I want to access the method "getOwner()" and "setOwner()" of an object "Aktie" in the method "buy()" in this ArrayList in the HashMap, but that isn't possible. :( But why??

Here ist the Code of the class "Boerse":

```
import java.util.*;
public class Boerse {

    HashMap<String,ArrayList> inventory = new HashMap<String, ArrayList>(); 
    HashMap<String,User> users = new HashMap<String, User>();
    Aktie[] Apple = new Aktie[10];

    /**
     * Main Methode der Klasse Boerse
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Boerse b = new Boerse();
    }

    /**
     * Erzeugt ein Objekt der Klasse Boerse
     */
    public Boerse()
    {
        FillInventory();
        System.out.println(inventory.get("Apple").toString());
        //buy("Apple", "Jonas");
        System.out.println(inventory.get("Apple").toString());
    }

    /**
     * Diese Methode fuegt dem Inventar die verfuegbaren Aktien zu
     */
    public void FillInventory()
    {
        /*
        *   //Sample
        *   ArrayList<Aktie> Sample = new ArrayList<Aktie>();
        *   int nSample = 0;
        *   double vSample = 0;
        *   Aktie aSample = new Aktie("Sample", vSample);
        *   for(int i=0;i<nSample;i++)
        *   {
        *       Sample.add(aSample);
        *   }
        *   inventory.put("Sample", Sample);
        */



        //Apple
        ArrayList<Aktie> Apple = new ArrayList<Aktie>();
        int nApple = 10;
        double vApple = 50.0;
        Aktie aApple = new Aktie("Apple", vApple);
        for(int i=0;i<nApple;i++)
        {
            Apple.add(aApple);
        }
        inventory.put("Apple", Apple);



        //Google
        ArrayList<Aktie> Google = new ArrayList<Aktie>();
        int nGoogle = 15;
        double vGoogle = 64.5;
        Aktie aGoogle = new Aktie("Google", vGoogle);
        for(int i=0;i<nGoogle;i++)
        {
            Google.add(aGoogle);
        }
        inventory.put("Google", Google);

        System.out.println(inventory.toString());
    }

    private void buy(String userName, String userPassword, String aktie,String pOwner)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<inventory.get(aktie).size();i++)
        {
            if(inventory.get(aktie).get(i).getOwner()==null) //here is the problem
            {
                inventory.get(aktie).get(i).setOwner(pOwner); //here is the problem
                break;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

And the class "Aktie":

```
public class Aktie {
    public double value;
    public String name;
    public String owner = null;

    /**
     * Erzeugt ein Objekt der Klasse Aktie
     * @param pName Name der Aktie
     * @param pValue Wert der Aktie
     */
    public Aktie(String pName, double pValue)
    {
        name=pName;
        value=pValue;
    }

    /**
     * Aendert den Besitzer der Aktie
     * @param pOwner neuer Besitzer der Aktie
     */
    public void setOwner(String pOwner)
    {
        owner = pOwner;
    }

    /**
     * Gibt den Namen des Besitzers aus
     * @return
     */
    public String getOwner()
    {
        return owner;
    }
}
```

Comment: `HashMap<String,ArrayList> inventory = new HashMap<String, ArrayList>()` should be `Map<String, List<Aktie>> inventory = new HashMap<>()`

Comment: try as JB Nizet specified or use type cast as below. Try using IDE's like Eclipse which gives you suggestions. It is easy way to find the options you have..

Answer (score 1):

try as JB Nizet specified or use type cast as below

```
private void buy(String userName, String userPassword, String aktie,String pOwner)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<inventory.get(aktie).size();i++)
        {
            if(((Aktie) inventory.get(aktie).get(i)).getOwner()==null) //typecast here
            {
                ((Aktie) inventory.get(aktie).get(i)).setOwner(pOwner); //typecast here
                break;
            }
        }

    }
```